# Inserting and retriving values into/from azure tables in c#

Tags: c#, azure-storage

I want to insert the values like location name, latitude, longitude into azure tables in c#. Since i was not good at using azure table, help me to make this happen.I have a free azure account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you search for that on the web?

Here is a link for what you are looking for of the official website:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/